# How to use ZFS on linux easily (without paths like /var/run/zfs) or as non-root

Tags: linux, zfs, fuse

When I asked about filesystems with compression I got [recommendation](https://superuser.com/questions/330316/how-to-get-enable-reiser4-on-kernels-2-6-38-are-there-alternative-fs-like-reis/330370#330370) to try ZFS. Looks like it worth trying, however I find tools that manage ZFS (`zfs`, `zpool`) quite overcomplexified - you need to create some volume, then add it, then create filesystem on it. And finally it suddenly created things in root directory like /qqq/test and it uses /var/run/zfs/zfs_socket (strange for a filesystem).

How to use ZFS (with FUSE) without it's complicated things with volumes, just as good filesystem with compression, something like `mount -o loop image.zfs /mnt/qqq -t zfs-fuse`?

How to setup ZFS as non-root? FUSE usually means "user can use it too" (example: ntfs-3g). I expect something like this:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/user/qqq.zfs bs=1M count=100
$ mkfs.zfs /home/user/qqq.zfs -o compress=gzip
$ zfs-fuse /home/user/qqq.zfs /home/user/mnt
```

Can ZFS be more usual FUSE filesystem that I can add to /etc/fstab and user can install and use on its own?

Answer (score 4):

Here is something close to what you are looking for, although you would need to be root to achieve it:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/user/qqq.zfs bs=1M count=100
# zpool create -O compression=gzip -m /home/user/mnt qqq /home/user/qqq.zfs
# chown user /home/user/mnt
```

ZFS supports non root operations (i.e. delegation) but ZFS-FUSE doesn't implement them.

Comment: OK, then question 2: Suppose some system have working FUSE (e.g. sshfs works), but zpool/zfs/zfs-fuse is not installed at all. How to install ZFS manually and create/mount ZFS as user? I expect it to use /home/user/var/run/zfs, not /var/run/zfs in this case.

Comment: There is probably no documented way to install ZFS manually as a user on Linux. Given the security implications, I even strongly doubt it to be doable at all.

Comment: security? What's wrong if user creates certain big file in his home directory and uses certain FUSE program to mount it to directory (without affecting other users). Security should just like in `mkisofs ... -o qqq.iso ; fuseiso qqq.iso $HOME/mnt/myiso`.

Comment: ZFS, being also an NFS and CIFS service and implementing POSIX ACL, set-uid bits, allowing setting arbitrary and persistent mount points and the likes cannot be implemented/mounted as is by a non root user without compromising the host security. What you are looking for would require to develop a stripped down version of ZFS and this hasn't been done.

Comment: It's a pity the ZFS-FUSE project did not yet take advantage of the ability of FUSE to run as a non-root user.  I guess that would be extra work above the basic porting.  If you control the box, you could set up a 'sudo' command to do what jlliagre suggested

Comment: This "file mapping" approach is expected to have lower performance compared to "native zfs-formatted partition", right?

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev It is expected indeed, given the extra file-system layer.